# .NET Core Authentication for Azure AD with MSAL

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs

I have a react app in which I'm using react-aad-msal to login to the Azure AD. After this I'm generating a token like so:

```
authProvider.getAuthProvider().UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(authParams)
        .then((res) => {
            let token = res.accessToken;
            axios.get('Employees/getCurrentEmployee', {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                }
            })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('emp', response.data);
                });
        });
```

I then pass this as a bearer token to my .NET Core API. The goal is lock down the APIs so that they are only accessible with a valid token from a logged in user. The Employee endpoint should return some simple info about the currently logged in user. I have done this previously with ADAL but since I have switched to MSAL I keep getting a 401 error like this: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

My .NET Core authentication is setup like so:

```
services
         .AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
         {
             sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         })
         .AddJwtBearer(options =>
         {
             options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
             options.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";
         });
```

I also call `app.UseAuthentication()` in the configure method as well.

I can't figure out if this authentication setup is no longer valid for MSAL or what. Any help?